# Difference between char and string

Tags: c++, string, character

A string is just an array of characters(has a '\0' or null character at the end). But when i use the getline function in c++,it gives me an error if i use char, but no error for string.
The following works:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout<<"Name: ";
    getline(std::cin,name);
    std::cout<<"Name: "<<name;
    return 0;
}
```

But when i use char instead of string.It doesn't work

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char name[50];
    std::cout<<"Name: ";
    getline(std::cin,name);
    std::cout<<"Name: "<<name;
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: You are mixing C string and C++ strings. _"A string is just an array of characters(has a '\0' or null character at the end)."_ That's true for C strings. `std::string` is a C++ string. They are fundamentally different.

Comment: For the sack of understanding you can say a string is character array with '\0' at the end but that is not that simple. std::string has many functions defined for it which won't work for character array.

Comment: `std::string` is actually a dynamic class-wrapper for the primitive C strings. `std::getline()` expects a `std::string` not `char*`. You may want to use `fgets(name, stdin, 50)` in this particular situation, but it is not *required* in context of C++ where `std::string` exists. Therefore, you will almost *never* find the need of having to encounter `char*`, `const char*`, etc. except in some significant cases where they are required (For example, if you are using some external C library).

Comment: A `std::string` is a class type that manages a collection of `char`s. An array of `char` is a raw collection of `char`s that are in a contiguous memory block - i.e. a completely different type. `std::getline()` has overloads for reading to a `std::string` but not for reading to a raw array of `char`. However, input streams have a member function to read to an array of `char` (but not to a `std::string`) so, in the second case, use `std::cin.getline(name, sizeof(name))` or (more crudely in your case) `std::cin.getline(name, 50)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of something like cs50.h in C, where `string` is a typedef of `char*`. That is not the case in C++, where `std::string` is actually a completely different type.

There is a form of [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) that you can use with `char*`, though not a free function. It is a member function of `std::istream`, which `std::cin` inherits. Here is your code modified to use it:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char name[50];
    std::cout<<"Name: ";
    std::cin.getline(name, sizeof name);
    std::cout<<"Name: "<<name;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C string and C++ strings.

*"A string is just an array of characters(has a '\0' or null character at the end)."* That's true for C strings. `std::string` in your code is a C++ string. They are fundamentally different. A C++ string is not an array characters. It's an object of class `std::string`. You can copy a C string into an C++ string and you can initialize a C++ string with C string. You can convert a C++ string to const C string with `std::string::c_str()`.

`std::getline` expects a `std::string` as second parameter. You can't use it with C string.

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a class composed by characters, and not an array of characters. It means that both types are different. See std::string definition: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

getline function needs an string. It will not work for a character array. See docs: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

A char is usually a single character from ASCII. for example a ,b ,c and others.

On the other hand a String is usually a collection or series places one after other. example "hello" , "hi Bro".